# How to fill the holes in my circle drawing algorithm?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

So I'm currently working on a python implementation of the Bresenham Circle Drawing algorithm and I'm facing an issue when I try to create concentric circles to add thickness to the border of the circle...

A Screen shot of the result I'm currently getting:
[image]

And there's holes in the border of my circle...

So I'm trying to fix my code in order to fill the holes.

My project structure is:

```
| - rendering
|   | - __init__.py
|   | - circle.py
|
| - main.py
```

Here's my main file:

```py
from pygame import Surface, Color, K_SPACE
import pygame

from rendering import Circle

circle1 = Circle((500, 500), 302)
circle2 = Circle((500, 500), 301)
circle3 = Circle((500, 500), 300)
circle4 = Circle((500, 500), 299)
circle5 = Circle((500, 500), 298)

fps        = 10000
resolution = width, height = 1000, 1000
clock      = pygame.time.Clock()
surface    = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)

while True:
    [exit() for event in pygame.event.get() if event.type == pygame.QUIT]
    clock.tick(fps)
    
    if pygame.key.get_pressed()[K_SPACE]:
        pygame.display.set_caption(f"Circle Bresenham: PAUSED")
        continue

    surface.fill(Color(0, 0, 0))

    pygame.display.set_caption(f"Circle Bresenham. { clock.get_fps() // 1 } FPS")
    
    a = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    circle1.render(surface, 2, Color(255, 255, 255))
    circle2.render(surface, 2, Color(255, 255, 255))
    circle3.render(surface, 2, Color(255, 255, 255))
    circle4.render(surface, 2, Color(255, 255, 255))
    circle5.render(surface, 2, Color(255, 255, 255))
    b = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    print(f"{b-a}ms")

    pygame.display.flip()
```

And here's my circle class:

```py
from dataclasses import dataclass

from pygame import Surface, Color

import pygame

@dataclass
class Circle:
    center: tuple
    radius: int

    def render_pixels(self, surface: Surface, x, y, color) -> None:
        surface.set_at((self.center[0] + x, self.center[1] + y), Color(255, 0, 0))
        surface.set_at((self.center[0] + y, self.center[1] + x), Color(255, 127, 0))
        surface.set_at((self.center[0] - x, self.center[1] + y), Color(255, 255, 0))
        surface.set_at((self.center[0] - y, self.center[1] + x), Color(255, 255, 127))

        surface.set_at((self.center[0] + x, self.center[1] - y), Color(255, 255, 255))
        surface.set_at((self.center[0] + y, self.center[1] - x), Color(127, 255, 255))
        surface.set_at((self.center[0] - x, self.center[1] - y), Color(0, 255, 255))
        surface.set_at((self.center[0] - y, self.center[1] - x), Color(0, 127, 255))


    def render(self, surface: Surface, thickness: int, color: Color) -> None:
        x = 0
        y = self.radius
        m = 5 - 4 * self.radius
        
        while y >= x:
            self.render_pixels(surface, x, y, color)

            if m > 0:
                y -= 1
                m -= 8 * y

            x += 1
            m += 8 * x + 4
```

Comment: Well, you're ignoring the `thickness` argument, but otherwise everything seems to be working correctly.   Bresenham circles drawn at incremented radii just don't make a filled disk.  How would you like to "fix" it?

Comment: Which version of pygame are you using?

Comment: @vakvakvak I'm using 3.12

Comment: @MattTimmermans Well if you go and see the image there's actually gap between each concentric circles and I was just wondering how to fill them 

I'm currently not using the thickness argument because I hardcoded the tickness in the main file

Comment: You can change the circle drawing so that it's *not* exactly Bresenham's, but will fill in those gaps (the diagonal parts of the circle will look a little thicker), OR you can implement the `thickness` argument and draw one circle instead of 5, OR you can do both.

Comment: @MattTimmermans Ok but I've not any idea on how to do that :(